# I am new to Java, is this a good coding technique?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn some java and I started with some assignments from codefights, and I just wanted to ask whether my coding technique is good or not ? for example is it okay to use break in for loops and multiple return statements ?

```
    boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) 
    {
          int i;                                                                                                
          int firstTry = 0;                                  /* to indicate the first try */         
          int secondTry = 0;                                 /* to indicate the second try */               
          int indexOfBreakingElement = 0;                    /* to indicate which index of the array is not following the almost increasing sequence */                           
          int sizeOfSequence = sequence.length;                                               
          int[] newFixedArray = new int[sizeOfSequence - 1]; /* an array used to store the edited or fixed array for further processing */                                             
          for(i = 0; i < sizeOfSequence-1; i++)
          {
                if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1])
                {
                      indexOfBreakingElement = i+1;
                      firstTry = 1;
                      break;
                }
          }


      if(firstTry==1)
      {
            for(i = 0; i < indexOfBreakingElement; i++)
            {
                  newFixedArray[i] = sequence[i];  
            }
            for(i = indexOfBreakingElement+1; i < sizeOfSequence; i++)
            {
                  newFixedArray[i-1] = sequence[i]; 
            }
      }

      for(i = 0; i < sizeOfSequence-2; i++)
      {
            if(newFixedArray[i] >= newFixedArray[i+1])
            {
                  indexOfBreakingElement = i;
                  secondTry = 1;
                  break;
            }
      }

      if(secondTry==1)
      {
            for(i = indexOfBreakingElement+1; i < sizeOfSequence; i++)
            {
                  newFixedArray[i-1] = sequence[i]; 
            }
      }

      for(i = 0; i < sizeOfSequence-2; i++)
      {
            if(newFixedArray[i] >= newFixedArray[i+1])
            {
                  return false;
            }
      }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Using `break` to leave a loop is just what it is intended for. As for multiple returns, some people will object but since they do not invert control flow (go back in code) they should be ok. But please remember the principle "do not use numbers for objects that are not numbers": Your `firstTry`and `secondTry` clearly should be booleans.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- but check their question guidelines first.

Comment: When writing code think of whats more efficient with best performance ..

Comment: Consider breaking that method up into smaller methods that each manage one piece of the overall logic.

Comment: Method is to long, 'brain overloading'; if(firstTry==1) magic number; Use  System.arrayCopy instead writing data copy loops; Use Java Array class  utility method etc. This code can be better.

Comment: You should also consider using Java's linq-equivalent features ala FirstOrDefault(), Any(), etc. Once you get the hang of it it will be the difference that makes the difference in readability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your coding technique is good (or at least acceptable).

Using `break` is perfectly fine in `for` loops. In fact, it suggest you may have advanced knowledge about `Java` as you already  demonstrate that you know that `break` will end the loop.

The same goes for using `return` multiple times as it demonstrates that you know that a function will stop running once it `return`s something, meaning that you know using multiple `return`s can improve efficiency.

Also, your frequent use of `for` loops demonstrates that you're comfortable using them, which is good. Your use of `i` and `j` as counter variables strengthens this impression.

Note: I would just like to point out that using lengthy variable names isn't the best practice as you're more prone to making a typo (that said, it's good that you're using camelCase for your variables).

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I have been coding in C for microcontrollers, and I have been told that it is a bad thing to have a break in a for loop or multiple return statements, however, currently I wanted to learn some Java, and that's where my question came from

Comment: @Wessam Adel a lot of things/details are considered bad practise (usually in general porgramming context). Luckly java is rather fail-safe and quit forgiving when it comes to performance. So just code/program away and get comfortable with the language before diving into 'best practise' and 'optimization', as optimizing is done by the JVM for a most part anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the method into smaller methods to show you an example of what I meant in my comment. See below. Multiple `return` or `break` statements, as well as a lot of variables, all in one method, can be hard to read. By breaking the logic up into smaller pieces it's more manageable. Three steps - find the breaking element, get the new fixed array, check it and return a `boolean` based on what it looks like.

```
public boolean isAlmostIncreasing(int[] sequence) {
    int[] newFixedArray = toNewFixedArray(sequence);

    for (int i = 0; i < newFixedArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (newFixedArray[i] >= newFixedArray[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private int[] toNewFixedArray(int[] sequence) {
    int[] newFixedArray = new int[sequence.length
                                - 1]; /* an array used to store the edited or fixed array for further processing */

    int indexOfBreakingElement = findBreakingElementIndex(sequence);

    if (indexOfBreakingElement > 0) {                   
        for (int i = 0; i < indexOfBreakingElement; i++) {
            newFixedArray[i] = sequence[i];
        }
        for (int i = indexOfBreakingElement + 1; i < sequence.length; i++) {
            newFixedArray[i - 1] = sequence[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 2; i++) {
        if (newFixedArray[i] >= newFixedArray[i + 1]) {
            indexOfBreakingElement = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sequence.length; j++) {
                newFixedArray[j - 1] = sequence[j];
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return newFixedArray;
}

private int findBreakingElementIndex(int[] sequence) {
    int indexOfBreakingElement = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
            indexOfBreakingElement = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return indexOfBreakingElement;
}
```

Comment: Ok, the simplest way. If you have an IDE like Eclipse, install https://www.sonarlint.org/ and check you code. Software will show  well known issues, with explanations.